# AngularJS, ng-switch fails if not wrapped into div giving: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives:

```
app.directive('uiElement', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {element: "=uiElement", search: "=search"},
    templateUrl: "/views/uiElement.html",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.isImage = function () {
        return (scope.element.type === 'image/png' || scope.element.type === 'image/jpeg');
      };
      scope.isList = function () {
        return (scope.element.type === 'text/list');
      };
      scope.isTodo = function () {
        return (scope.element.type === 'text/todo');
      };
    }
  };
});
```

And the associated template:

```
<article class="uiElement" ng-class="{typeImage: isImage(), typeList:isList(), typeTodo:isTodo()}" ng-switch on="element.type">
  <div><div class="inside" ng-switch-when="image/png">
    <i ui-image="element"></i>
  </div></div>
  <div><div class="inside" ng-switch-when="image/jpeg">
    <i ui-image="element"></i>
  </div></div>
  <div><div class="inside" ng-switch-default>{{element.name}}</div></div>
</article>
```

As you can see each `ng-switch-when` has:

```
<div><div class="inside" ng-switch-default>{{element.name}}</div></div>
```

A double div, and I think this is bad templating. However if I remove the divs:

```
<article class="uiElement" ng-class="{typeImage: isImage(), typeList:isList(), typeTodo:isTodo()}" ng-switch on="element.type">
  <div class="inside" ng-switch-when="image/png">
    <i ui-image="element"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="inside" ng-switch-when="image/jpeg">
    <i ui-image="element"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="inside" ng-switch-default>{{element.name}}</div>
</article>
```

**Update:** I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3003/js/angular.min.js:47:448)
    at Object.applyFunction [as fn] (http://127.0.0.1:3003/bubble/5116f5a9cfbecf42ad000006:440:50)
    at Object.e.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:3003/js/angular.min.js:84:307)
    at Object.e.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:3003/js/angular.min.js:86:376)
    at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:3003/bubble/5116f5a9cfbecf42ad000006:500:30)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:3003/js/angular.min.js:92:400)
    at n (http://127.0.0.1:3003/js/angular.min.js:95:472)
    at XMLHttpRequest.q.onreadystatechange (http://127.0.0.1:3003/js/angular.min.js:96:380)
```

However if I use the template code without divs directly into the html page (without using the directive, it works)

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem.

I was using a JQuery component inside my directive's template and I was initializing it like so in the controller:

```
$element.find('.crappy-component-target').crappyComponent();
```

Turns out that this component/library was messing up with Angular.
There were two solutions to this problem:

1. Move the component initialization code inside the link function of your directive.
2. Wrap the `.crappy-component-target` element inside a `<div>` element.

Either of the above solved my problem.
I guess that's a case of many, where crappy JQuery-style components don't go along with Angular. And most of the times it's Angular that takes the blame...

Comment: Had same problem with TinyMCE. Issue is gone after wrapping it with a `div`. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Same issue with a button that had an ngClick directive that wasn't working (no console error, just didn't fire). Had a `textarea` that I was initializing CodeMirror on a couple of elements before it. Wrapping that `textarea` in a `div` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error message. The code was something like this:

```
<div><div class="foo">Some element</div></div>
<div class="bar">{{String I'm trying to add to previously working div}}</div>
```

I moved the div I was editing above the double-div element (the order on these didn't matter) and it worked fine.  Not sure exactly what the problem was, but it does seem that nested divs are a factor.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar problem. I am not sure why but removing `replace: true`(set it to false) of the directive solves this problem.

Maybe I should make an issue of this.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with

```
  <select ng-model="approvals.TimeFilterSelected"
                ng-options="item.name for item in approvals.TimeFilterSelect"></select>

        <p>Selected: {{approvals.TimeFilterSelected || 'None'}}</p>
```

If that code is in nested div which is some levels down after the div which holds the ng-controller - it dosn't work. Moving that just after the controller div works fine. What should we do in these situations if we want to keep the same structure of html ?!! Can that be Angular bug?  I do not see any issue with my HTML formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue with a slightly different error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:3841:35)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:4217:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:3827:14)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:4217:24)
    at angular.js:4358:15
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:4217:24)
    at angular.js:4357:13
    at angular.js:8625:11
    at wrappedCallback (angular.js:6586:59)
    at angular.js:6623:26
```

This is with AngularJS v1.0.1

I can also confirm that surrounding my ng-switch-when  with another  solved the issue.  But it would be great to know why it happens and how it could be avoided.